# what are most commonly used JMeter listeners

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing and using listeners for getting the response results but I am not sure which are the most commonly used listeners which will give data for analysis.

I know Table view and tree view but those basic ones, kindly advice which listeners should I use.

Comment: Listeners should be used during smoke testing of your script and should not be used in actual load test because they are resource hungry (memory specifically). Summary report and Aggregate report are generally used to get mean, max, avg response time, error rate etc. data required for data analysis.

Comment: @NachiketKate _"Listeners should be used during smoke testing of your script and should not be used in actual load test"_ - that's not true. **Some** of them are memory hungry, and are not recommended for real load (e.g. tree view). But it doesn't mean that all listeners should be avoided during load tests. In fact only very simple load tests can run without any listeners. How else would you investigate failures, or analyze bottlenecks?

Comment: "In fact only very simple load tests can run without any listeners" - I think you should read blazemeter blog "jmeter performannce tuning and tips". "How else would you investigate failures, or analyze bottlenecks?" - I believe people use jtl files for that purpose. post-processing is always preferred in such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter documentation provides a [very good overview of the listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and when/how to use them.

- While you are debugging and developing your plan, there's nothing better than [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), which also serves as a tester for RegEx, CSS/JQuery and XPath tester. However this particular listener **must be disabled** or deleted during the real load test, as it will eventually crash JMeter with OOM exception.
- During the real load test you need to record statistics (how long requests took, etc.) and errors. In non-interactive mode, the best is to use [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) with CSV format, which is considered to be very efficient. If you use interactive mode, or both (interactive and non-interactive modes), it's very convenient to use [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or 
  [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report), since they display stats right away, and you can see immediately if something goes wrong. They also have ability to write to file, just like Simple Data Writer.
- Finally, if you want to include some custom result collecting (not provided by any listeners), you can use [BeanShell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) or [BSF Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Listener)

In terms of organization, I find it convenient to separate successes and failures, so I always have 2 listeners:

- For **successes** (in "Log/display only" option *Successes* is checked) I either record only statistics using Aggregate/Summary report (if test will run interactively and for a long time) or record file in CSV format (if I need a raw data about each request).
- I always record **failures** (in "Log/display only" option *Errors* is checked) into file in XML format (for example using Simple Data Writer). XML format is not that efficient, but test is not supposed to have many failures (if it does, basically it should be stopped and analyzed). But XML format allows to record failing request and response headers and body, which is convenient for further debugging.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While executing the test better to avoid adding the listeners, only thing you can add simple data writer alone from that listeners you can generate any type listeners as you need.

while making the script ready you can use any type of listeners that will no be any issues.